# Every smooth function on $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}$ is the curl of some vector field

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given a smooth function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}$, there exists some smooth vector field $F : \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f = \mathrm{curl}\,F$. In other words, it is possible to find smooth functions $F_1, F_2 : \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
f = \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x_1} - \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x_2}.
$$
One way to prove this is to show that the (de Rham) cohomology group $H^2(\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\})$ is trivial, but this usually involves additional machinery (e.g., the Mayer–Vietoris sequence). Does anyone know of an *elementary* proof of this result?

Comment: @RossMillikan The function $f$ is defined over $2$-dimensional space, so there isn't a way of taking the divergence.

Comment: Yes, choose $F_1 = 0 $. Then use the elementary fact that every continuous one variable function has an antiderivative.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I don't think that works because of the puncture at $0$. Take $f(x, y) = 1 / (x^2 + y^2)$, for instance. Then the antiderivative $y^{-1}\arctan(x / y)$ is not defined everywhere.